# How to Navigate Wikileak Torrents (wlstorage.net)?

Tags: data-request, leak

I can download Wikileak files from either wlstorage.net or file.wikileaks.org but I'm having difficulty identifying the files of interest.

For example, at http://wikileaks.org, you see "DNC Email Archive," and "AKP Email Archive," but I have been unable to match those with an entry for the Wikileaks archives. Dates don't help because the archives all list as 01-Jan-1984.

Am I missing a well-known mapping file to the archives?

Comment: with serious caution...the past few weeks they've been bundling a lot of malware with their downloads. proceed at your own risk

Comment: I have seen the malware reports, but prefer authentic data dumps. Using stolen data entails risks, take proper precautions.

Answer (score 1):

Each individual "Leaks" package often have a link to the direct download from files.wikileaks.org. You don't necessarily need to use the torrents

Here's an example -- start at https://wikileaks.org/podesta-emails/

Scroll down to "Download entire raw dataset for all published Podesta Emails here", which is a link to https://file.wikileaks.org/file/podesta-emails/

which gives you links to the gzipped folder or individual files.

---

But in your case, they don't yet offer the files as individual downloads or torrents. I don't know of any official reason why some datasets aren't yet available. It could just be backlog, or it could be some editorial reason.